# JavaFx Charts and getting values for Y Values from XYChart.Series knowing the X values

Tags: java, charts, javafx

I'm attempting to replicate something I've hand crafted in the past but I'm keen to move this to JavaFX Charts so I know longer need to  maintain it myself. I can get the XAxis and YAxis values from a chart relatively easily based on the location of the mouse pointer. But I now need to know what the series value (and I might have many) is. I then plan to display this in a box that floats over the charts as shown in my hand crafted chart.

I'd post an example image but sadly my reputation is currently too low.

I know I can do this by manually recording very value add to the chart in a Tree Map and then polling it as the mouse moves to determine the values... But I'm curious if there's a simpler approach that doesn't require me to repeat code from my existing non JavaFX chart.

I can't find anything in XYChart.Series or Observable List that would simplify this process so I'm just trying a sanity check before I hand crank it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

But your X must be a Number value

```
private Data<X, Y> getNearestDataForXValue(X xValue, Series<X, Y> series) {
    Data<X, Y> nearsetData = null;
    double distance = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    for (Data<X, Y> data : series.getData()) {
        double xData = data.getXValue().doubleValue();
        double dataDistance = Math.abs(xValue.doubleValue() - xData);
        if (dataDistance < distance) {
            distance = dataDistance;
            nearsetData = data;
        }
    }
    return nearsetData;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Got to this myself but thanks for the feedback